# Matching HTTP_HOST in rewriteCond?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two servers that are running for my app.

prod and staging as below.

I need to execute some redirect rule if the HTTP_HOST matches [www.sitedomain.com](http://www.sitedomain.com) or stage.sitedomain.com

if  the URL is https://www.sitedomain.com/us-en   page should redirect to https://www.sitedomain.us/

and if the URL is https://stage.sitedomain.com/us-en  page should redirect to https://stage.sitedomain.us/

I am executing the following steps

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sitedomain\.com$ [NC]                                  1
RewriteRule ^/us-en/(.*)$   https://www.sitedomain.us/$1      [R=301,L,NC]            2

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stage\.sitedomain\.com$ [NC]                                 3
RewriteRule ^/us-en/(.*)$   https://stage.sitedomain.us/$1      [R=301,L,NC]           4
```

The  problem is  whenever I am hitting https://stage.sitedomain.com/us-en I am redirecting to https://www.sitedomain.us/, not to https://stage.sitedomain.us (simply saying it never reaches line Number 3)

So line number 1 always executing as True, and rewrite rule at line2 executing for stage URL.

Can anyone help me to solve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Make sure this is the very first rule of your htaccess Rule file. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|stage)\.(sitedomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-.*/?$ https://%1.%2.$1/ [NE,R=301,L]
```

---

---

In case you want to only apply these rules to un-es urls then try following, make sure you either use above OR following rules at a time.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|stage)\.(sitedomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(us)-en/?$ https://%1.%2.$1/ [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: @saravanan baskar, could you please do let me know if this has worked for you?

Comment: Yes, Ravinder this solution solved my issue... literally spent few hours on this..  Great thanks.....
But do u have any reason why my code mentioned above in question is not working as expected...

Comment: @saravananbaskar, I could see 2 major things in it, one is regex is not used properly and 2nd is your RewriteRule part checks `^/` which is not correct it doesn't start match from `/` hence it will not match it in any condition cheers and happy learning